# If X is the rate out of Y number of words, then what is the rate out of a thousand words?

Tags: math, sampling, rate

I am sorry if this seems like a stupid question. For some reason I just can't get my head around it.

EDIT: What I mean is: If I have a text of 132891 words, and I can calculate the percentage of each word, how do I normalize it as if the rate reflected a thousand words?

Comment: If it's a percent, it's always per 100 words. If you want to say per 1000, just take the percent and multiply it by 10. Getting the percent is as easy as (x / y) * 100

Answer (score 0):

```
X * 1000 / Y
```

You have to multiply X with the same number as the number you need to get from Y to 1000.

Of course this is the same as

```
( X / Y ) * 1000
```

So if you have Y = 132891 words, and word X occurs 8125 times,
word X would occur 1000 * (8125 / 132891) times in 1000 words.